# Does LibGit2Sharp support cloning a multiple repositories?

Tags: c#, libgit2sharp

I am using `LibGit2Sharp` to access a remote `Git` repository. The scenario is as follows: Clone the repository from a remote URL using `Repository.Clone` method. How to solve this issue?

```
foreach (string repo in repositories)
{
    string url = @"https://bitbucket.org/" + requestedAcct + "/" + repo;
    string cloneDir = repoDir + repo;

    try
    {
        LibGit2Sharp.Repository.Clone(url, cloneDir, creds);
    }
    catch
    {
        string msg = "Handled LibGit2Sharp exception";
        MessageBox.Show(msg);
    }
}
```

- > TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'NotificationManager.Repositories.GitHubSingleton' threw an exception.
- > LibGit2SharpException: request failed with status code: 404

Comment: Just saying: Visual Studio went away from libgit for a reason. We also switched to git.exe in our legacy Build-Tool (which is usually a "don't touch" software).